# Bootstrap Form Helpers country and state not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add this bootstrap form helper to my form but for some reason nothing is populating. What's missing? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2fy1me4y/

Source: http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/state.html

```
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label>State</label>
                <select id="countries_states1" class="input-medium bfh-countries" data-country="US"></select>
                <select class="input-medium bfh-states" data-country="countries_states1"></select>
                <small class="text-muted">Provide the state you currently reside</small>
            </div>
```

Comment: I think this was sovled here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929769/how-to-insert-bootstrap-form-helper-country-picker-to-a-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example I created of it working. Please note I didn't use the CDN you had in your fiddle because I couldn't get it to work. Didn't dig much into it.

https://jsfiddle.net/5bbnt7xc/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="countries_states2" class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#"> <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span> <b class="caret"></b> </a>
    <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
        <div role="listbox">
            <ul role="option"> </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-states" data-country="countries_states2">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#"> <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span> <b class="caret"></b> </a>
    <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
        <div role="listbox">
            <ul role="option"> </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```